# Send email to recipients in MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

I'm working on a website in which, when a person enters email in the box, it will save it to MySQL DB.

I want to make a page, when once visited, will send email to the recipents in the DB. My script is here:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT email FROM subscribers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo $row["email"]. "&nbsp";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$to = "";
$subject = "PrakashSoft Website has been Lauched!";
$txt = "Respected Mam/Sir,

    PrakashSoft Website has been lauched from 3rd May 2015! To visit the website use the following link:

    http://www.prakashsoft.esy.es/home.php";
$headers = "From: noreply@prakashsoft.esy.es";

mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
$conn->close();
```

So, I'm trying `$to` to get those multiple emails from DB and then sending them an email which I've typed. What should I do to do that? I know I've left `$to = "";` blank.

Comment: `$to = 'mail1, mail2, mail3';`

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
  $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email)
    FROM subscribers";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $to = $row["email"];
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks. Edit: I tried to do that. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}    

$sql = mysql_query("select email from subscribers");
    $recipients = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $recipients[] = $row['email'];
    }

    $to = implode(",", $recipients);
    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $body = "E-mail body";
    $headers = "From: noreply@prakashsoft.esy.es" ;

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

This would work

Comment: It shows following errors:

`Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'localhost'@'10.2.1.20' (using password: NO) in /home/u808741660/public_html/working/email.php on line 14`


`Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/u808741660/public_html/working/email.php on line 14`


`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u808741660/public_html/working/email.php on line 16`